# JUnit 5 test case result not reflecting even changed the logic

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I am trying to use junit5 in spring-boot application in intelliJ IDE. I am getting issue in not reflecting result of junit test when I run it individual. while I run using  mvn clean install command, my test cases gets executed and work fine but when I run it individual test case, result remain same . its always showing last result which I got from cmd mvn clean install..even I have changed code. its not reflecting.  Below are using:

```
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
```

below are dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My test case:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestingApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertEquals("abc", "abc");
    }
}
```

if I change it to

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestingApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertEquals("abc", "123");
    }
}
```

and run again this single test with right click "Run" it will be passed if last result from mvn install was passed.
My question is why its not reflecting my result?. it should fail in second case.

Comment: are you sure your IDE has compiled It? because when you are runing you are using the IDE as you say you click run, check the warnings from your IDE

Comment: yes @vmrvictor I am able to compile it and there is no warning. :(

Comment: can you try mvn clean install

Comment: yes I had tried with mvn clean install but no change. @techiesantosh

Comment: Please show the full runnable example. There are quite a few thing that can go wrong, eg filtered out class names, wrong imports etc.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Please do check the versions of Junit in main module and sub module of maven project.
There can be a chance, because of which it behaves like this